# Cascading matches in robots.txt

Tags: search-engines, robots.txt

I was wondering if it's possible to let bots match two groups of `User-Agent:` blocks.

I have this block of robots.txt

```
User-Agent: AhrefsBot   # https://ahrefs.com/robot/
Crawl-Delay: 5

User-agent: *
Disallow: /error.php
Disallow: /cron.php
... and many more rules ...
```

Now, I wonder if AhrefsBot will now respect the crawl-delay and also respect the rules in `user-agent:*`?
If not, then I'd have to duplicate everything under `user-agent:*` which would be quite unhandy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an User-Agent is mentioned generally it only reads the rules mentioned below it. Most possibly AhrefsBot will not respect rules in `user-agent:*` and you need to duplicate the rules. Here is example from twitter and facebook robots.txt to support my opinion. They have duplicated rules for all bot specifically mentioned.
`https://twitter.com/robots.txt`
`https://www.facebook.com/robots.txt`